# Is there a modified version of PuTTY which doesn't produce one line per print job?

Tags: putty

We've been using PuTTY to access a SCO Unix system for some time now and we've recently found the need to use pass-through/slave printing to a client printer attached to the Windows machine accessing the system.

However, this appears to create a print job per line rather than a single print job with every line within. I have heard there's a modified version of PuTTY floating aroudn which handles this type of printing correctly.

Does anyone know of its existance/where to get it or have any other suggestions?

So far I've tried:

- Multiple drivers
- Capturing the output on LPT1 and converting it into a single file then printing, unfortunately this was prone to error and would take too much work.
- Multiple printers
- Printing to image-based printers and PDF generators

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I've tried the following clients now, with no change:

1. KiTTY
2. Quest PuTTY
3. AniTa 32
4. Aljex Terminal

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest option is probably to ping [Simon Tatham](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/passthru-default-printer.html), and beg for pass through printing to be included in the next PuTTY release, alternatively you could evaluate a number of the other Windows **ssh** clients, to see how functional their printing support is e.g.

[Tectia Client](http://www.ssh.com/index.php/products/tectia-ssh-client.html),  [AbsoluteTelnet](http://www.celestialsoftware.net/), [smartFTP](http://www.smartftp.com/client/features/ssh)

As a stop gap have you tried this [script](http://perlsquirrel.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/korn-shell-perl-putty-pass-thru-source.html)?

Comment: Pass-through printing is actually included in PuTTY and it does work, it's just that it tends to print 1 line per page rather than a full document. Some printers can interpret the slew of jobs as one page, but others won't. Unfortunately its the "others" that are causing me problems

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the program inside-out, so I don't know if it is capable for this, but maybe [KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) is the one you're looking for..

Comment: Gave it a go, unfortunately it exhibits the same problem